# the right answer is go \ to go\goes\going

Tags: grammaticality

I'd prefer to go to the face-painting stall.
I'd prefer goes to the face-painting stall.
I'd prefer go to the face-painting stall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I'd prefer goes to the face-painting stall" is not correct.
"I'd prefer to go to the face-painting stall" is fine.
You can also say " i'd prefer going to the face-painting stall".